# Automator workflow - connect to server when locked onto a specific network (Wi-Fi/Ethernet)

Tags: macos, network, applescript, automator

I'm trying to get Automator to complete the following workflow:

1) IF Wi-Fi network is "Network_Name1" or "Network_IP1" (or any other way to identify a specific network connection):

- **TRUE**: Jump to 3
- **FALSE**: Jump to 2

2) IF Ethernet Thunderbolt Slot network is "Network_Name2" or "Network_IP2" (or any other way to identify a specific network connection):

- **TRUE**: Jump to 3
- **FALSE**: Workflow complete (nothing will happen in this case)

3) Complete the following actions:

- **Get specified server**
- **Connect to server**

I don't know how to complete arguments/expressions 1 and 2. Anyone able to help please?

When identifying a network, could you please outline the most relevant way to identify a specific network?